# Guice: instantiating a singleton before creating the module

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Is it possible to instantiate and assign a singleton to a reference with Guice before creating the Module and pass that instance to the Module constructor be bound during configuration?

Here is an example of what I mean:
I have a method that allows me to create objects depending on a custom implementation of an interface which is being passed in constructor as an Optional (if the user won't provide a custom implementation, we will use the default one), which is being done by binding the interface to that particular implementation in the Module class. :

```
public static MyClass createMyClassObject(Optional<SpecialInterface> customSpecialInterfaceObject) {

    SpecialInterface specialInterfacebject;

    if(customSpecialInterfaceObject.isPresent() {    
        specialInterfaceObject = customSpecialInterfaceObject.get()
    } else {
 /* here I would like to bind it to an instance of the DefaultSpecialInterfaceObject but can't really do something like:
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(myClassModule);
DefaultSpecialInterface instance = injector.getInstance(DefaultSpecialInterface.class);
as the module is yet to be created */
}
    MyClassModule myClassModule = new MyClassModule(specialInterfaceObject);
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(myClassModule);
     return injector.getInstance(MyClass.class);
}
```

I'm currently using classes instead of instances to solve this problem, such as in the example below, but I don't quite like this solution. Would be happy to see a better way of doing it:

```
private static Class resolveSpecialInterfaceObject(Optional<SpecialInterface> customSpecialInterfaceObject) {
    Class specialInterfaceObjectClass;

    if (customSpecialInterfaceObject.isPresent()) {
        specialInterfaceObjectClass= customSpecialInterfaceObject.get().getClass();
    } else {
        specialInterfaceObjectClass = DefaultSpecialInterface.class;
    }
    return specialInterfaceObjectClass;
}

public abstract class MyClassModule extends AbstractModule {

    private final Class<SpecialInterface> specialInterfaceObjectClass;

    public MyClassModule(Class<SpecialInterface> specialInterfaceObjectClass) {
    this.specialInterfaceObjectClass= specialIntefaceObjectClass;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(SpecialInterface.class).to(specialInterfaceObjectClass);
        }
}
```

**Edit, from a comment below:**

> one more thing- didn't want to make the question too long; actually, I also want to perform another operation on the resulting instance of SpecialInterface, but only if it is the instance of DefaultSpecialInterface and I don't think it should be done in the Module. I was thinking if I could just have this bean up and running before, such as in Spring, so I could just pass it to the Module, but also use it in another method call before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you take the whole `Optional` and use `bind(...).toInstance(...)`?

```
public static MyClass createMyClassObject(
        Optional<SpecialInterface> customSpecialInterfaceObject) {

    MyClassModule myClassModule = new MyClassModule(customSpecialInterfaceObject);
    Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(myClassModule);
    MyClassFactory instance = injector.getInstance(MyClassFactory.class);
    return instance.createMyClassObject();
}

class MyClassModule extends AbstractModule {
  private final Optional<SpecialInterface> customObject;

  MyClassModule(Optional<SpecialInterface> customObject) {
    this.customObject = customObject;
  }

  @Override public void configure() {
    if (customObject.isPresent()) {
      // Singleton by necessity: Guice doesn't know how to create another one.
      bind(SpecialInterface.class).toInstance(customObject.get());
    } else {
      // Default scoped. Add ".in(Singleton.class)" if necessary.
      bind(SpecialInterface.class).toInstance(DefaultSpecialInterfaceClass.class);
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to perform additional initialization on DefaultSpecialInterface and nothing else, you have a number of options:

- If some kind of initialization is important for all implementations and likely too heavy to put into a class constructor, add an `initialize` method on your SpecialInterface. Make the custom one a no-op, and implement it for DefaultSpecialInterface.
- If the initialization is unique to DefaultSpecialInterface, I see no reason why it shouldn't be in the Module. Write a `@Provides` method or bind to a `Provider<SpecialInterface>` that creates and initializes DefaultSpecialInterface correctly.
- If your real goal is to keep the business logic out of a Module, you can do so by extracting it into a free-standing Provider or DefaultSpecialInterfaceFactory that *is* responsible for that.

Remember, Guice is responsible for feeding fully-constructed objects into your object graph, and that means that injecting a SpecialInterface should get a ready-to-use implementor of the SpecialInterface general contract. If Guice needs to perform some initialization to make that happen, it's not unreasonable to have it do so, and a Module isn't a bad place to do it.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Bowman - this looks better. It does not yet solve my full problem, but that's because I have not added one more thing- didn't want to make the question too long; actually, I also want to perform another operation on the resulting instance of `SpecialInterface`, but only if it is the instance of `DefaultSpecialInterface` and I don't think it should be done in the Module. I was thinking if I could just have this bean up and running before, such as in Spring, so I could just pass it to the Module, but also use it in another method call before? I guess that wouldn't work here?

Comment: You're welcome! I'm editing the answer now, but in the future **please ask the entire question or split it up into independent sub-questions**. Otherwise, how would we ever know whether our solution works in your bigger problem until after we've put in the work to write a possibly-irrelevant answer? Even if it makes for a long question, it's much more respectful than adding constraints later.

Comment: Ok. Thanks @Jeff Bowman, I guess I will try to use Providers.